# how tags are different from elements in HTML

Tags: html

At w3schools.com they define like this:

> An HTML element usually consists of a start tag and end tag, with the
>   content inserted in between:
>
> `<tagname>Content goes here...</tagname>`

Can anyone explain?

[image: two muppets]

Comment: what is your question . Can you more specific please?

Comment: <body>Hello stackoverflow</body>      In this which part is called tag and which part is called element

Comment: The answer is already in your quote.

Answer (score -1):

```
<body>Hello stackoverflow</body>
```

For this example, `<body>` is an html tag.
But complete of line is an element.